# Onclick HTML does't call Javascript function inside PHP "echo"

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to call the Javascript function 
It's working if I use in Html

```
<input type="button" value="Click Me"  onclick="$.notify('Error: Sign in before Join.', 'error');" class="nk-btn">
```

But I wanna use that code in **Php echo""** but doesn't work

```
echo" <input type='button' value='Click Me'  onclick='$.notify('Error: Sign in before Join.', 'error');' class="nk-btn"> "
```

because of Using Single quotes insted of Double:

How to call js function in another way??

Comment: JavaScript can't call functions declared in PHP files. You have to request the PHP file and then within that file determine what code should run.

Comment: @ScottMarcus It looks like OP is saying using `echo` to output the element with the onclick method does not work, not that they are trying to call a PHP function from JS.

Comment: You could break out of PHP rather than using an `echo` statement - or use [HEREDOC](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) syntax if you like... but I'd be amazed if there's not a functional duplicate for this on SO already tbh.

Comment: Instead of echoing the string, just end the PHP block `?>`, write your HTML and then when you're done, start the PHP block again `<?php` and you won't need to care about escaping the quotes.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Actually we can! You can check Answer below! Solved

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\` to escape quotes in php.

```
echo "<input type='button' value='Click Me'  onclick=\"$.notify('Error: Sign in before Join.', 'error');\" class=\"nk-btn\">"
```

Your problem is that you are using the same quotes for your `onclick` and inside the `$.notify`
The same with the class

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like

`echo "<input type='button' value='Click Me'  onclick='$.notify('Error: Sign in before Join.', 'error');' class='nk-btn'>"`

or

`echo "<input type='button' value='Click Me'  onclick='$.notify('Error: Sign in before Join.', 'error');' class=\"nk-btn\">"`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of messing around with escaping quotes in the string, just close the PHP block, write the HTML and open a new PHP block again after it, if needed:

```
// Some PHP
?>

<input type="button" value="Click Me"  onclick="$.notify('Error: Sign in before Join.', 'error');" class="nk-btn">

<?php 
// More PHP
```

This will not only free you from escaping the quotes, but most IDE's can syntax highlight the HTML as well (which helps with readability and debugging)

#### However

A better way would probably be not to have the `onclick` attribute on the element at all but rather register an [even listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) directly in js.